# Allign shapes and text in SVG for PDF generation

Tags: svg, fonts

I would like to generate some diagram style graphics using SVG and use text in the diagrams. My problem is, how to know the size of the text in advance to be able to adjust the rest of the layout accordingly. To make this explicit: I'm not talking about SVG in a browser. I would like to work with fixed units and generate PDF for printing for example. So if I use a 12pt font, it should also be printed as 12pt font.

To have a more concrete example: Lets assume I have the three strings "bla", "blablub" and "blubblablub". I would like to print them in a given 12pt font, determine the string size and enclosing boxes and draw the biggest sized box around all of them. The idea is to have equally sized boxed around all, based on the longest text.

Could somebody give me a hint how to do that or why it is not possible? Searching for this topic, I only get some JavaScript tricks in the browser, which usually involves rendering the text and then re-rendering everything again.

Comment: Is there a reason to do the text in the SVG, instead of making a latex/xelatex document that includes the svg files as graphics and adds real text, with real, precise, fonts that will always render the same when told to generate to pdf?

Comment: I want to layout diagrams automatically, so I need to be able to position text and boxes free. At least based on my current latex knowledge it would not be possible in LaTeX. But in theory I take everything that tells me upfront the size of texts, so my layout/algorithm can adapt.

Comment: what do you mean "free"? Positions are hardcoded in SVG, so whether it's hard coded in SVG or in LaTeX, it's still hard coded, and LaTeX is designed to be guaranteed the same every time it runs, unlike SVG which doesn't have a universally supported font mechanism.

Comment: I know LaTeX as a system, which layouts your text and where you cannot say "Position this piece at (15,35) and the other at (80,90)". Please correct me, if I'm wrong. Hardcoding as in SVG is exactly what I want. I want to write the layout algorithm and the output should look exactly like my algorithm specifies it. If you think that can be done via LaTeX, I'm happy to get a pointer to where to start reading.

Comment: you most certainly can, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20792/how-to-superimpose-latex-on-a-picture